# What's an appropriate way to find out from a potential employer how often pay rises and layoffs occur?

Tags: salary, layoff

Someone I know (went to the same university and friends on Facebook, haven't talked to them in almost three years now) works at the company I've applied for and this company has given me an offer. It is a bit low compared to my current salary, but I don't like my current job (new role is more technical than what I do), my current employer has layoffs on a yearly basis for 7 straight years now in its 40 year existence, and more interested in the specific technology field that this other company works on.

How can I ask how often this company rewards its employers and how often redundancies occur (if ever)? This will affect my decision and I didn't get a chance to ask the question to the people who interviewed me (not sure how to do it properly anyway).

Comment: You mention you have a friend from University there - have you asked them yet?

Answer (score 5):

Glassdoor.com is a pretty good resource to see how companies treat their employees, but don't treat it as completely trustworthy (in the same was as Trip Advisor reviews can be slanted)

You'll want to Google around and form a balanced decision for yourself.

Having yearly lay-offs for technical staff isn't typical in my experience.

Comment: I had one (and only one) employer that did yearly layoffs.  Every January they'd come up with whatever excuse sounded good, lay off a bunch of people, pay at least 2 weeks per year of employment, and then they're done.  Quick and dirty.  So with this employer if you came to work one January and a bunch of people were laid off but you survived, you knew with full confidence that barring any big reason to be fired your job was good for at least one more year.

Comment: Lots of fake reviews that shine positive or negative. Good way to tell if a review is one sentence long, 5 stars, and person claims to work there less than a year.

Answer (score 5):

Recommend going on Linkedin.com, connecting to people that used to work there BUT DO NOT ANYMORE, and ask them via connection request.  These people would know such things as raises and layoffs and would not have a reason to withhold that information from you.